# How to loop through rows via row indexes - R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame (dat_gs2) that is 12 rows by 17 columns. I am looking to loop through each row in two columns and use them to calculate the value of a third column. The problem i am facing with the below code is that the keyword "in" is getting flagged as "unexpected token in". If i try to run this block of code I get the error below. I am not sure what the problem is. Any help appreciated

> "Error in `[.data.frame`(dat_qs2, i, 11) : object 'i' not found"

```
    LoopIters<-1:12

    i=1



    For (i in seq_along(LoopIters))
    {
      if ((dat_qs2[i,11]/dat_qs2[i,13])<.25)
        {
          dat_qs2[i,14]<-"Low"
          next
        }
      else if((dat_qs2[i,11]/dat_qs2[i,13])<.75)
        {
          dat_qs2[i,14]<-"Medium"
          next
        }
      else if((dat_qs2[i,11]/dat_qs2[i,13])>=.75)
        {
          dat_qs2[i,14]<-"High"
          next
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is very likely that you can do this without a `for loop`. How about post a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: In addition to the other comments and answers, the seq_along() is doing nothing since you already defined `LoopIters` as `1:12`.  Also you do not need `i=1` and that's what is causing your problem.  LoopIters already starts at 1.  If you set i to 1, you are saying `for(1 in 1:12)`  which  doesn't make sense. 1 is definitely in 1:12 and always having i =1 is really not what you want.  Also `for` should be lower case.

Answer (score 1):

here is without loop :

```
dat_qs2[ ,14] <- ifelse(dat_qs2[,11]/dat_qs2[,13]<.25, "Low", 
                 ifelse(dat_qs2[,11]/dat_qs2[,13]<.75, "Medium",
                         "High"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve the same result. Without seeing the actual data, I'm assuming the column names in your data frame.

```
library("tidyverse") # or library("dplyr")

dat_result <- 
    dat_qs2 %>%
      mutate(newcolumn = ifelse(columnName11 / columnName13 < 0.75, "Medium", "High")
             , newcolumn = ifelse(columnName11 / columnName13 < 0.25, "Low", newcolumn)
```